# Error when creating customer cube with measures and dimension

Tags: msbi

I tried to create a cube with measures and dimension, but I got the following error. How can I fix this?

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>SSAScustomerv</DatabaseID>
        <CubeID>Customer Data Ware House</CubeID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

> ```
> Processing Dimension 'Dim Country' completed.
>     Start time: 11/01/2018 14:03:32; End time: 11/01/2018 14:03:33; Duration: 0:00:00
>     Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
>         Start time: 11/01/2018 14:03:32; End time: 11/01/2018 14:03:32; Duration: 0:00:00
>     Processing Dimension Attribute 'Country Id' completed.
>         Start time: 11/01/2018 14:03:32; End time: 11/01/2018 14:03:33; Duration: 0:00:00
> Errors and Warnings from Response
> Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSOLAP$ANANTHSQL'.; 28000.
> Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Customer Data Ware House', Name of 'Customer Data Ware House'.
> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Country', Name of 'Dim Country' was being processed.
> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Country Id' attribute of the 'Dim Country' dimension from the 'SSAScustomerv' database was being processed.
> Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
> ```

Comment: Can you show your code so far please. A minimal verifiable example would be good.

Comment: Hi Ari, I have posted the error above  which gave while running  the cube.